# minecraft java edition does not want to work

Tags: java

when i try to play minecraft java, it shows me this:

Unable to locate the Java runtime.

Error details: Success
Filename on disk: java
Path: /usr/bin/java
Exists: Directory

So minecraft does not want to work...

Answer (score 1):

Which launcher are you using?

Mojang has an official Minecraft launcher available that is packaged as a .deb file. This is the traditionally recommended method, but not the only one.

You can find this at https://minecraft.net/download/alternative.

You can install the .deb via the CLI using `sudo apt install /path/to/Minecraft.deb`, or use a tool like Eddy from AppCenter to do it with the GUI.

Beyond this, there is a Flatpak available on Flathub. You can download the .flatpakref file from https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.mojang.Minecraft by hitting the "Install" button on the page.

To install, you just need to open the downloaded Flatpak and Sideload (elementary OS's Flatpak helper) should walk you through it.